# Multi-key dictionary with optional keys

Tags: c#, .net-3.5, dictionary, hashtable

I have a need for a dictionary with multiple keys of 2 different types (int and string, both unique, so they can appear only inside of 1 key). Here is an example: group information (GroupInfo) can be queried by either GroupdId or one of the member names:

```
GroupId   MemberNames           GroupInfo
{1,       John, Mary, Joe} ==>  {GroupInfo}
```

So group info should be returned when requested by either id (1) or one of the member names (John).

My first solution was to create a key that wraps GroupdId and MemberNames with overridden Equals method that compares GroupIds and looks up a list of members. However to make these entries equal:

```
GroupId   MemberNames          
{0,       John}
{1,       null}
{1,       Mary}
```

GetHashCode has to return the same const value. This will result in a dictionary becoming a linked list and performance degrading to O(N) lookup in the best case scenario.

The other solution is to keep 2 dictionaries separately: GroupId ==> GroupInfo, MemberName ==> GroupInfo.

Any other ideas?

Comment: Can you convert the GroupId into a string so you can use a single dictionary?

Comment: What is your objection to just using the two dictionaries? It is simple and obviously correct.

Comment: @Philipp +1 for a good solution that I havent thought about. That'd do, but how'd you delete by a key? For example given a key "John" all other keys should be deleted as well.

Comment: I don't know if the dictionary lookup allows this, but can you define custom comparators - one that looks at `id`, one that looks at `MemberName`?

Comment: @Philipp, i decided to follow your advice and make GroupId be just one of the keys inside of the dictionary (there won't be collisions between Ids and members) and make the values maintain the back references to the keys, so that if one gets deleted, the rest will be deleted. Can you convert your comment to an answer, so I can accept it?

Comment: @keteroh done, but I am not sure how to interpret your comment about the back references.

Comment: `class Entry { string[] keys, GroupInfo }` and `Dictionary<string, Entry> map`. So the above entry would have: `Entry entry = new Entry(new string[] { "1", "John", "Mary", "Joe" }, new GroupInfo()); map.Add("1", entry); map.Add("John", entry);` and so on.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to maintain only 1 dictionary, consider converting the GroupId (int) into a string and use it as a key (number 'keys' should not conflict with name keys). Maintain a references to the keys, so that if one gets deleted, the rest will be deleted.

Answer (score 4):

Based on what you described in your comment

> how'd you delete by a key? For example given a key "John" all other keys should be deleted as well.

It may have become clear to you now that a "Dictionary" isn't what you are looking for. Mostly because you have a need for multiple key types, and a need to map keys to other keys.

So you can create your own class that implements IDictionary. Basically as follows.

```
    class MultiKeyDictionary : IDictionary
{
    Dictionary<string, GroupInfo> stringDict = new Dictionary<string, GroupInfo>();
    Dictionary<int, GroupInfo> intDict = new Dictionary<int, GroupInfo>();
    Dictionary<GroupInfo, List<object>> keysDict = new Dictionary<GroupInfo, List<object>>();

    //Each of these would add to their own dictionary, as well as adding the backwards
    //entry in the "keysDict"
    public void Add(string memberName, GroupInfo value);
    public void Add(int key, GroupInfo value);

    public bool Contains(string key);
    public bool Contains(int key);

    //This would be the enumerator of the "keys" of "keysDict"
    //because it is actually a list of all GroupInfos
    public IDictionaryEnumerator GetEnumerator()

    public ICollection NameKeys;
    public ICollection GroupIDKeys;
    //This is to adhere to the interface. It should be carefully commented or even deprecated.
    public ICollection Keys;

    //For this, you look up the GroupInfo for the key, then do
    //foreach(object key in keysDict[<groupInfoIJustLookedUp>]) {
    //   if(key.gettype == typeof(string) stringDict.Remove(key);
    //   else if (key.gettype == typeof(int) intDict.Remove(key);
    //   else //WHAT?!?
    //}
    public void Remove(string key);
    public void Remove(int key);

    //This would be the "Keys" collection of the "keysDict"
    public ICollection Values;

    //etc... etc...
    public object this[string memberName];
    public object this[int groupId];
}
```

Comment: that'd work, thanks, but it'd be eventually encapsulation of 2+ dictionaries that i didnt want to do

Comment: @kateroh Why don't you want to do that? You've created a brittle solution that relies on your keys not overlapping with each other (works for your situation, but not for a general case), and the effort of maintaining two dictionaries is completely abstracted away so that for the users/coders of the app, they don't need to care. The interface for them will be exactly as it was before, except that your code is now much more adaptable for the future.